# How do muggle-born students have enough money to go to Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

How do muggle-born students have money to go to Hogwarts? It's very expensive, and if neither of the parents were wizards they wouldn't have money for the wizarding world.

Comment: What makes you think it is particularly expensive?  If the Weasleys could afford it, the average Muggle family would surely be able to.  If you can't, however, funding is available from Hogwarts, that's how Tom Riddle was able to attend.

Comment: Related: [Where do Hogwarts students get money from while they're at school?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/155141/31394)

Comment: This is directly addressed in the [highest voted answer on the duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63047/20774). Poor students are given money for supplies and the education itself is free.

Answer (score 14):

- **Tuition is never mentioned, just supplies.**

Harry's only costs are his trips to Diagon Alley.  The school does not charge him to attend.  Needless to say, books, supplies, and especially wands are not cheap, but they're not expensive to the level of preventing people from attending.

- **Muggle money can be changed for Wizard's gold.**

Hermione's parents are seen in Diagon Alley during *Chamber of Secrets*, about to enter Gringott's.  They are able to use their Muggle money there to allow them to shop for supplies elsewhere.

- **There's help for those who need it.**

Tom Riddle was assigned funds to help him get through his school years, as he had no parents to support him.  The Weasleys manage to get by having sent/sending seven children through the school, despite the apparent cost in supplies.  It works out.